# Динамический массив массивов

Tags: c, массивы

У меня есть файл со списком точек и их координат в трехмерном пространстве. Мне нужно хранить их координаты в массиве (где индекс- номер точки) массивов.

К примеру точка

```
(i = 0 : 0.000, 214.000, 73.000)
```

Должна выглядеть как

```
coords[0][0] = 0.000; coords[0][1] = 214.000; coords[0][2] = 73.000;
```

Количество точек известно (записано в начале файла), но может меняться, так что мне потребуется динамический массив (malloc), а вот измерений всегда будет 3. Как лучше мне реализовать это, учитывая то, что в дальнейшем мне придется обходить этот массив для поиска соседей (точек, находящихся в пределах заданного радиуса)?

Если использовать такой способ, (Nat- количество точек)

```
float* coords = (float*)malloc(Nat * 3 * sizeof(float));
```

то у меня выйдет одномерный массив. Этот способ хуже (в плане быстродействия), чем следующий, где я выделяю память под массив указателей на массивы координат (состоящие из трех элементов)?

```
float** coords = (float**)malloc(Nat * sizeof(float));
```

И еще одно- во втором способе как мне присвоить указателю адрес нового (пустого) массива? В C ведь нет "new". Можно это и здесь сделать через malloc, но мне кажется это излишним, ведь размер здесь задается не переменной, он всегда 3. Так нет ли способа сделать это как-нибудь наподобие

```
coords[i] = new int[3]
```

?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать массив структур?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы будете заниматься расширением массива *часто*, то его стоит сделать как можно более простым, так что в этом случае я бы делал его одномерным и использовал либо структуру

```
struct point { double x,y,z; }
point * p = malloc(....);
```

И обращение к элементам как к

```
p[i].x, p[i].y, p[i].z
```

или как одномерный же массив троек (если нужно обращаться именно через индекс) -

```
double * coord = malloc(3*sizeof(double)*.....)
```

и обращаться через

```
coord[i*3+0], coord[i*3+1], coord[i*3+2]
```

Замедления не будет, потому что именно в такое обращение компилятор превращает

```
coord[i][j]
```

в двумерном массиве.

В варианте

```
double ** coord = malloc(3*sizeof(double*));

coord[0] = malloc(sizeof(double)*....);
coord[1] = malloc(sizeof(double)*....);
coord[2] = malloc(sizeof(double)*....);
```

будет сложнее работать при изменении количества точек (потребуется три `realloc`'а вместо одного).

Comment: Расширение массива не потребуется. Мне нужно будет выделить память лишь 1 раз.
Спасибо большое, вариант со структурой выглядит лучше всего.
Единственное- использование структур так же не скажется на скорости? Мне нужно будет обрабатывать довольно большой объем данных и быстродействие здесь самое важное.

Comment: "Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол" (с) Кнут :)

Answer (score 1):

Да используйте статический массив это круче.Проверяйте вход через макрос:

```
#define check_s(i,max_buf,func,var) if(i>max_buf){ms0;_e_(func,var);}
#define _e_(func,var) \
printf("in func->%s\n",func);printf("var->%s\n",var);
#define ms0 printf ("Static memory error\n")
#define md0 printf ("Dinamic memory error\n")
#define ne0 printf ("Null error\n")
```